# Hiding errors until the user leaves the input

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm actually creating my form with inputs ! I created a `state` in the bottom of each `TextInput` to judge if the user input is true or false!! However, when I run my App it gives me by default everything false it makes sense then because the inputs are all blank! I want those errors to be hidden by default and to be shown until the user leaves every single input!! This is the example of one input

**signup.js**

```
this.state{
   mail:""
}

...

<TextInput
  onChangeText ={(value)=> this.setState({mail : value})} 
  style={{
    width:200,
    height:40
  }}
  placeholder='xyz@email.com'
/>

...

render () {
  const regexMail = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

  const mail = this.state

  return (
    ...

    { regexMail.test(mail) != true 
      ? <Text>Mail invalide</Text>
      : <Text>Mail valide</Text>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
<TextInput onChangeText={(value) => this.state.mail = value}
    onBlur={() => this.forceUpdate()}
    onFocus={() => {
       this.state.mailTouched = true;
    }}
    style={{
        width: 200,
        height: 40
    }} placeholder='xyz@email.com' />
```

Comment: but the  forceUpdate( ) contains what ??

Comment: It's an inbuilt method which will re-render the component again.

Comment: But in default when i run my App It shows me the errors Should i work on the forceUpdate to make hide my inputs in default view

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting you. Can you please explain again?

Comment: I have blank inputs by default !! So when i run my app it shows me by default those errors ..!! I want those errors to be hidden until the user touch the inputs , enter values and leave  ! Then , it will be even false or true !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212010/discussion-between-zakaria-belassal-and-rajan).